# How to expand a Spotify Shortened URL into Full URL?

Tags: swift, spotify, urlsession

At some point, recently (in 2023 I think), Spotify rolled out shortened links, which broke many developers' code. You can read more about it [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Give-us-an-endpoint-to-decode-new-shortened-share-links/td-p/5523686).

The shortened links seem to go through multiple redirects in an unorthodox way.

This seems to fix the issue in Python:

```
def expand_short_url(short_url_string):
    try:
        response = requests.head(short_url_string, allow_redirects=True)
        return response.url
```

...and you'll see a similar line in the Spotify Community post I linked above:

```
import requests
r = requests.head("<spotify.link url>", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
```

...but it appears there is no easy way to do this in Swift because Swift (and SwiftUI, which incorporates Swift) does not seem to have as robust a way of conducting URL sessions as Python does.

Here is the use case:

This is the Spotify shortened link:

```
https://spotify.link/H6FTskvicDb
```

...and if I paste it into Google Chrome it redirects to:

```
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5zPbGYMyILmVCty6TJ9mOO?si=IkYKRaG5S5-6S_QY0YEYeg&utm_source=copy-link&utm_medium=copy-link&nd=1&_branch_match_id=1159194084012404754&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8soKSkottLXLy7IL8lMq9TLyczL1vcwcwspzi7LTHZJAgAyNUUSIAAAAA%3D%3D
```

...which at least is a full URL.

But when I try to expand the same link in SwiftUI:

```
func expandShortURL(shortURLString: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: shortURLString) else {
        print("Invalid URL: \(shortURLString)")
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    // Set a common browser User-Agent
    request.setValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: RedirectFollower(), delegateQueue: nil)
    session.dataTask(with: request) { _, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("URL Expansion Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              let finalURL = httpResponse.url else {
            print("Failed to get final URL")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        print("Final URL: \(finalURL.absoluteString)")
        completion(finalURL.absoluteString)
    }.resume()
}

   class RedirectFollower: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
            if let url = request.url, url.absoluteString.contains("open.spotify.com/playlist/") {
                // We've reached our target URL, stop following redirects
                completionHandler(nil)
            } else {
                // Continue following redirects
                completionHandler(request)
            }
        }
    }
```

...this can only expand the link to:

```
https://spotify.app.link/H6FTskvicDb?_p=c11334dc9f057af2e21e90fce1b0
```

The good news, at least for now, it that Spotify has seemed to move away from the shortened mobile links for now, but if anyone knows how to crack this, from ChatGPT to the depths of the internet, I've seen no one with a way to do in Swift what seems to work so swiftly in Python.

Comment: What's `RedirectFollower()`? If you don't set it? On a real device, I got "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5zPbGYMyILmVCty6TJ9mOO?si=IkYKRaG5S5-6S_QY0YEYeg&utm_source=copy-link&utm_medium=copy-link&nd=1&_branch_match_id=1258007793156753008&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8soKSkottLXLy7IL8lMq9TLyczL1vcwcwspzi7LTHZJAgAyNUUSIAAAAA%3D%3D" with a GET and strangely "https://www.spotify.com/us/download/mac/?_branch_match_id=1258007793358688030&utm_source=copy-link&utm_medium=sharing&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8soKSkottLXLy7IL8lMq9TLyczL1vcwcwspzi7LTHZJAgAyNUUSIAAAAA%3D%3D" with a HEAD...

Comment: Thanks, Larme. I've added in the RedirectFollower class so you can see it, the idea was trying to follow the redirects. This special Spotify shortener link seems to be smart enough to change it's behavior depending on the environment (mobile vs desktop and probably OS too), so it's vexing. I will see if I playing around with GET makes a difference.